# Change the result of RANK() based on conditions in other columns

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, ranking, row-number

Now I have a table in redshift like this:

Table Project_team

```
Employee_ID   Employee_Name     Start_date    Ranking      Is_leader   Is_Parttime_Staff
Emp001           John           2014-04-01      1           No             No
Emp002           Mary           2015-02-01      2           No             Yes
Emp003           Terry          2015-02-15      3           Yes            No
Emp004           Peter          2016-02-05      4           No             No
Emp004           Morris         2016-05-01      5           No             No
```

Initially there is no ranking for staff. 
What I do is to use the rank() function like this:

```
RANK() over  (partition by Employee_ID,Employee_Name order by Start_date) as page_seq
```

However, now I want to manipulate the ranking based on their status. If the employee is leader then he or she should be ranked at the first. If he or she is parttime staff then should be ranked at the last. The table should be sth like this:

```
Employee_ID   Employee_Name     Start_date    Ranking      Is_leader   Is_Parttime_Staff
Emp003           Terry          2015-02-15      1           Yes            No
Emp001           John           2014-04-01      2           No             No
Emp004           Peter          2016-02-05      3           No             No
Emp004           Morris         2016-05-01      4           No             No
Emp002           Mary           2015-02-01      5           No             Yes
```

I tried to use the case function to manipulate it like

```
Case when Is_leader = true then Ranking = 1 else RANK() over  (partition by Employee_ID,Employee_Name order by Start_date) End as page_seq.
```

However it does not work.

What is the process that I need to change the ranking based on other conditions in other columns?

Many thanks!

Comment: Use the `case expression` inside the over clause of relevant window function.  Suggested solutions below use this approach but fail to state the actual solution.

Answer (score 1):

use dense_rank()

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=052d800f90a25f93f7ab2452f0269c93)

```
select *,dense_Rank() over(order by case when leader='yes' then 1 else 0 end desc, case when parmanent='yes' then 1 else 0 end) 
from cte1
```

output:

```
id  name    leader  parmanent   employeerank
1   A        yes    no          1
3   C        no     no          2
2   B        no     yes         3
```

Comment: @fa06 Many thanks! But still have a problem, for the other rows that is neither Is_leader nor Is_Parttime_Staff, I still want to keep them in the original order i.e rank with employee_id. How ca n I do that?

Comment: you mean both value are no - in this case what you want ?